# Unable to instantiate 'InvalidJavadocPosition' class

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I am using `Gradle 5.5.1` and wanted to add `checkstyle` plugin.

I added plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

And took `sun_checks.xml` from [sun_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml).
But when I try to execute `gradlew clean check` it fails with exception that is caused by

```
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate 'InvalidJavadocPosition' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as
.InvalidJavadocPosition, InvalidJavadocPositionCheck, .InvalidJavadocPositionCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to config
ure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.createModule(PackageObjectFactory.java:210)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:127)
        ... 110 more
```

As far as I understand it is caused by the rules that are not supported by default checkstyle version that gradle uses `8.17`.

However when I wanted to change the tool version like this (updated to higher position)

```
checkstyle { toolVersion '8.21' }
```

it did not resolve the issue. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sun_checks.xml file for which you provided a link is the latest version of the code, in GitHub.  If you follow that link you will see that the InvalidJavadocPosition check module was added 22 days ago:

"rnveach Issue #6649: add InvalidJavadocPositionCheck 2b7b0c2 22 days ago"

The InvalidJavadocPositionCheck class was also added to the checkstyle codebase in GitHub 22 days ago, destined for version 8.23:

https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/InvalidJavadocPositionCheck.java

```
* @since 8.23
*/
@StatelessCheck
public class InvalidJavadocPositionCheck extends AbstractCheck {
```

So the sun_checks.xml file that you are using is compatible with 8.23 which has not yet been released.

Simple workaround is to remove the module until 8.23 is released:

```
<!-- <module name="InvalidJavadocPosition"/> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You must always use the config that matches your toolVersion. So, for Checkstyle 8.21, the file to use is
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-8.21/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml

Adjust the version number according to your Checkstyle version.